# How to select multiple arrays using check box in PHP? Also how to click and select single check box in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

In my code the selection of all items is possible
I am using a java script to check all and it properly works.But when check one of them from this table, I can't do it.One value is inserted.How it possible to select separately.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<SCRIPT language="javascript">

$(function () {
    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
        $('.name').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });
    // if all checkbox are selected, then check the select all checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".name").click(function () {
        if ($(".name").length == $(".name:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }
    });
});
</SCRIPT>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
$(function () {

// add multiple select / deselect functionality

$("#selectall").click(function () {

    $('.name').prop('checked', this.checked);
    if (this.checked)
        insertText();

});



// if all checkbox are selected, then check the select all checkbox

// and viceversa

$(".name").click(function () {



    if ($(".name").length == $(".name:checked").length) {

        $("#selectall").prop("checked", "checked");

    } else {

        $("#selectall").prop("checked", false);

    }

    insertText();
});


function insertText()
{
    var arr = [];
    $('.name:checked').each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).val());
    })

    $('.text').val($arr.join(','));

}



});
```

Comment: thanks for your response...but its not working in my case..if i select one check box using this code...only name is taken...the corresponding array text boxes not inserting

Comment: i update code. you can change this text class for your class!

Comment: ..i tried this code..this time data inserted twice when i click checkbox...my problem stil there...in my table i have separate checkboxes for each row..i need two conditions 1.select all when click single check box..(it is working) 2.choose one or two..so i need to select seperatly..here where am struggling...please help me..